# Calculating viewBox parameters based on path elements in SVG

Tags: svg, viewbox

I get an XML or JSON with paths only, and I need to recreate the SVG image.

I create an empty

`<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'></svg>`,

I add a `<g transform="scale(1 -1)" fill='#aaa' stroke='black' stroke-width='5' ></g>` in it, and then in this element I add all of the paths in it (e.g. `<path d=` ... `/>`).

In the end I get a SVG image, but because I haven't set the viewBox attribute in the SVG element the image isn't properly displayed - when I open it in browser, a part of it is displayed full size.

Can the viewBox be calculated from the values from the paths?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "a part of it is displayed full size" ?

Comment: For example if I have a 400x400px SVG, a par of it - e.g. a 50x50 from the down left corner - I get it full size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so I solved it the following way:

1. removed all letters from the paths string and made an array out of it with

   `var values = pathValue.split('L').join(' ').split('M').join(' ').split('z').join('').split(' ');`
2. found max and min from those values:

   `var max = Math.max.apply( Math, values );`

   `var min = Math.min.apply( Math, values );`
3. set the viewBox:

   viewBox = max min max max

This worked in my case excellent. Hope that it will be helpful to someone else too.

Comment: That sounds good. I understand the problem now. Initially I thought you could just set the viewBox to a fixed value, but I guess that wouldn't work because if the image is too big, part of if won't get displayed.

Comment: nice : > btw an easier way to do the values bit: path.match(/(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)/gi). this also works with other characters like q and t which can be in paths

Comment: note that splitting a path this way to find the extent works ONLY if the path are polygonals; any circular arc or cubic/quadratic spline, or positioned text elements within the SVG may extend outside the bbox computed this way. There's a solution for arcs and splines, but it requires converting them to polygonal lines up to some level of precision where you are sure it will not escape the bounding box; for text it is more complex as it requires computing font styles, and extracting glyphs. Additionally strokes have a width, and you need to take into account the miter/circle/butt joining types.

Comment: Finally, animation in SVG may move elements outside their initial position.
It is always a good solution to include in the SVG some dummy rectangle (unfilled and without stroke borders) that define the intended area where the rest will be drawn.

Comment: How will it works for arcs and bezier that has outer curves (concave)?

Answer (score 19):

Similar to Martin Spa's answer, but a better way to do get the max viewport area is using the getBBox function:

```
var clientrect = path.getBBox();
var viewBox = clientrect.x+' '+clientrect.y+' '+clientrect.width+' '+clientrect.height;
```

You can then set the viewbox to these co-ordinates.

n.b. i think you can change the viewbox of an svg after it's rendered so you may have to re-render the svg.

Comment: Perfect just what I needed.